# SELECT COUNT takes too long in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I cant find out why this query takes too long time. It takes around 1 minute 30 seconds to return result ( there are around 45 million not null rows btw ) and the table size is 11 GB.

```
select count(x) from y where x is not null;
```

PostgreSQL version is 11.7 and there were lots of dead_tup(like 800k) on the table which i executed vacuum on the table yesterday night and it decreased n_dead_tup to around 500-600ish.

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Finalize Aggregate  (cost=1328153.31..1328153.32 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=7833.185..7833.185 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                     |
|  ->  Gather  (cost=1328153.09..1328153.30 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=7833.178..8065.137 rows=3 loops=1)                                                                           |
|        Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                                                           |
|        Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                                                          |
|        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=1327153.09..1327153.10 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=7829.184..7829.184 rows=1 loops=3)                                                          |
|              ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using tableName_x_idx on y(cost=0.57..1280520.76 rows=18652933 width=37) (actual time=0.068..6912.224 rows=14912984 loops=3)|
|                    Index Cond: (x IS NOT NULL)                                                                                                                                |
|                    Heap Fetches: 1193002                                                                                                                                            |
|Planning Time: 0.110 ms                                                                                                                                                              |
|Execution Time: 8065.182 ms                                                                                                                                                          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

the execution time shows 8 seconds but it is because it is fetched from the cache.

I also see time to time, n_dead_tup count increases for this table. I suppose, not only deleting the data increases the n_dead_tup count? Can updating on the table also increase this value?

I also tried creating an index specifically for the column which it didn't work either.

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY ON Y (x) WHERE x IS NOT NULL;
```

tableName_x_idx is unique index

Comment: As you already have `where x is not null` try `select count(*)` instead.

Comment: It doesn't change anything on execution plan

Comment: But `count(*)` is a bit faster than `count(column_name)` - but your where condition returns about 80% of all rows in the table. A Seq Scan is the fastest way to get that count. I doubt there is any index that will speed this up

Comment: But if it was using seq scan, wouldnt i see that using on execution plan? like `Seq Scan on y (cost...)`. `show enable_seqscan;` is on but it doesnt use that

Comment: The Parallel Index Only Scan is just as good in this case.

Comment: Can updating on the table also increase this n_dead_tup value by the way?

Comment: Turn on track_io_timing and the do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` after waiting long enough for the cache to normalize.

Comment: Do you have long-lived transactions?  That VACUUM didn't drop  n_dead_tup further and also didn't "cure" the high number of heap fetches suggests maybe you do.

Comment: "the execution time shows 8 seconds but it is because it is fetched from the cache."  If this is executed frequently, why doesn't it just stay in the cache?  And if it executed infrequently, why do you care if it takes 1:30?

Comment: Using `count(*)` instead of `count(x)` would also allow use of an index-only bitmap scan.  I have no idea if that would actually be advantageous here, but it would at least be an option.